# I cant access my databases on mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp, ampps

I set up ampps on mac os, and configured all files. However when I launch mysql server and access the command prompt, I have access only to `Applications/AMPPS/var/mysql` (this is where mysql directory is). After placing my databases inside and launching the "SHOW DATABASES;" command, I only have the following output:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| databases          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

while there should be 5 more files inside.
Using the `USER();` command, I got the following:

```
SELECT USER();
+----------------+
| USER()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+


mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```